# How to list key pairs assigned to running AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

How can I check which key pairs are allowed to be used for connecting to running Amazon EC2 Instance?

I can see instance itself inside console as well as key pair list. Unfortunately this particular instance is not created by me and I don't have private key of creator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the **name** of the keypair associated with an Amazon EC2 instance. However, if you do not have the private keypair, you will not be able to access the instance.

Actually, a few points to clarify this:

- When a **Linux instance** is launched from an Amazon-provided AMI, the private keypair is copied to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The content of this file can be changed later, so any user with a keypair defined in that file can login as `ec2-user`. You can also create additional Linux users and add authorized_keys for them.
- When a **Windows instance** is launched from an Amazon-provided AMI, a random password is generated for the `Administrator` user. The password is encrypted using the public half of the nominated keypair and can then be decrypted with the private half of the keypair. The password can be changed using normal Windows commands, in which case the decrypted keypair is no longer valid.

Worst case, if you cannot login to an instance, you can gain access to the disk and change the password/keypair. There are help pages online to assist with this task, but it requires AWS permissions to manage the EBS disks.

By the way, the above is all related to the Operating System. Amazon EC2 does not control access to the OS, but it has some scripts on the AMIs that configure the instance on first boot.

**Bottom line:** The displayed keypair is required when starting an instance for the first time. If you have been handed an existing instance, there's no way to know how to login without being told or taking a look at the configuration.